# How to crop a twitter bootstrap carousel image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, crop

I'm trying to make a "fullscreen carousel" which i have successfully done using twitter bootstrap. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

Fairly straightforward procedure, i've got the carousel working fine.

However, while I want the width parameter to be 100% (So the width of the image always fits 100% of whatever the user's screen size is), i want the top and bottom of the image to be cropped off equally by about 20% each. So 60% of the image should be left. I obviously don't want the image to be warped by shrinking it.

HTML - The Carousel code (effectively the same as found in bootstrap, with the addition of database elements and href links)

```
echo'<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>';
        for ($i = 1; $i < $rows; $i++){
        echo'<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="'.$i.'"></li>';
        }
echo'</ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->';
      $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($r2, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo'<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
        <a href="Article.php?id=' . $row2['ArticleID']. '">
         <img src="'.$row2["BackgroundImage"].'" alt="..."></a>
          <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>'.$row2['ArticleTitle'].'</h3>
          </div>
        </div>';
    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($r2, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo'<div class="item">
          <a href="Article.php?id=' . $row2['ArticleID']. '">
           <img src="'.$row2["BackgroundImage"].'" alt="..."></a>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>'.$row2['ArticleTitle'].'</h3>
                </div>
        </div>';
    }
echo'</div>
```

css

```
.carousel {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}
.carousel-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

I'm probably missing something simple, but I can't seem to find anything that cuts off a percentage of the image from the top or bottom.

Comment: People could help you better if you posted the relevant code.

Comment: This could really use an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

The answer was a lot simpler than a lot of websites explaining how to crop an image were making out. Use the correct margin call on the side you wish to crop out. The negative margin effectively crops the image.

```
margin-top: -10%;
```